# Notice: Undefined variable: key in comment_prepare_thread() /public_html/modules/comment/comment.module)

Tags: comments

I'm getting two errors based on comments by users that no longer exist. I just updated from Drupal 6 to 7, and this seems to be an error that pops here and there, but I can't figure out how to fix it. The errors are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: key in comment_prepare_thread() (line 901 of /home2/cheffrog/public_html/modules/comment/comment.module).

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type comment. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7734 of /home2/cheffrog/public_html/includes/common.inc).

[This](http://www.nicklitten.com/blog/notice-undefined-variable-key-commentpreparethread-line-900-commentmodule) is an article I came across that talks about the issue.

The problem is that, when I try `SELECT * FROM`comment`WHERE uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM users)`, it lists every user in my database, including the registered users.

The pages on which this error is triggered are inaccessible. However, if I edit the page and change all the comments to hidden, the page will display fine, minus the comments.

I have this error happening on a lot of pages, so I'm hoping there's a better fix than just hiding all the comments on every single page.